# How to change from Wi-Fi to 3G while iPhone is receiving an audio stream?

Tags: iphone, audio, streaming, nsurlconnection, core-audio

My iPhone application plays a wma audio stream over the mms:// protocol.

When the Wi-Fi connection drops it won't switch to 3G to continue streaming. I have enough buffer to play for another 15 seconds (I tried to increase the buffer size, but it will stop anyway).

What sort of mechanism can I implement so the playing won't stop and the iPhone changes from Wi-fi to 3G?

In other posts I saw that it should do it automatically, but in my case it doesn't, because its wma over mms protocol.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be talking out my butt, however, you could try detecting the Error from the connection when it fails. and restart the stream from your buffered location so you can resume the download. If the internet is down the iPhone should reconnect it to accommodate your new request for the mms feed.

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for the suggestion. I'll set up some NSLogs on key points to see how it goes.

Comment: Sure thing, I will. Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, that helped me solve the problem!